# Alibaba ECS Instances do not respond to ping on private network unless I set password

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have the following configuration in `Alibaba ECS`:

[Public Connector and Three Test Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TBXt.jpg)

`Connector` has network connections on the public internet and the default `VSwitch` in the default `VPC`. `Connector` was created using the ECS web interface. The `testnode[0-2]` machines were created in a script using the Alibaba cli command: `aliyun.`

When the instances start running, the connector can ping none of them. If I set a password on any of the test nodes, and then restart the test node, ping starts working. The script uses a snapshot of the `Connector` as the image for the test nodes. The ```Connector`` has a randomly generated, long, and forgotten root password. Root access is via ssh with a passphrase protected key pair. It also has the same for a non-root user for the test code.

What I have tried is creating test nodes with the following `CreateInstance` options:

1. No `--Password` and no `--InheritPassword` options (original intent: why set a password? I have the access I need from the Connector image)
2. `--InheritPassword` option (I need a root password in order for the private network interfaces to work, the root password in the Connector image is fine)
3. `--Password` option (I need to explicitly set a root password on the test nodes)

The result is all the same, until I use the ECS web interface to set a password and restart a test node, `Console` cannot ping the test nodes.

**What I know:**

1. This is not a problem with the default security group, VPC, or VSwitch as I touch no settings on these entities in order for ping to work.
2. This is not a problem with the instance image because as soon as ping works, ssh to the test nodes works as well.

What I am doing wrong, or what am I missing? The whole purpose is to spin up instances without having to type away at the ECS web interface. I figured out what it took to get the private network traffic moving because I wanted to debug the situation on the test nodes, and for that, I had to set a root password and gain access from the ECS web console, which again, defeats the purpose of scripting.

`Aliyun` command for creating the test nodes:

```
aliyun ecs CreateInstance --ImageId m-2vchb2oxldfuloh51wp9 --RegionId=cn-chengdu --InstanceType=ecs.c6.xlarge --SpotStrategy SpotWithPriceLimit --SpotPriceLimit 0.25 --ZoneId cn-chengdu-a --InternetChargeType PayByTraffic --InternetMaxBandwidthOut 99 --InstanceName TEST_NODE-0 --HostName testnode0 --Password 'notgoingtotellyou'
```

Operating system for all instances is **Ubuntu 18.0.4.**

Aliyun command **version is 3.0.30.**

Comment: I guess you'd better submit a ticket to the Alibaba team.

Comment: Based on @Anduin's excellent advice, I opened a ticket. Will share in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got **two answers**. One from a co-worker. One from Alibaba.

**Co-worker's answer**:
The configuration fails because the **Unbuntu 18.0.4** image that I created for the non-public test machines used a static address for the internal network interface. I changed the internal network interface (`eth0`) to use dhcp and all worked. See [netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples) for how to change the IP address assignment.

**Alibaba's answer**:
Try using `aliyun ecs RunInstances` instead of three individual `aliyun ecs CreateInstance` and `aliyun ecs StartInstance` invocations. I did not try this solution as it would have involved rewriting my scripts. Alibaba could have done more to motivate me by providing an explanation as to why `RunInstances` would produce a different result than the combination of `CreateInstance` and `StartInstance`.